# Find $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}$ of $z=f(u,v)$ where $u=\frac{\sin x}{y^2}$ and $v=\frac{1}{y}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We have a function $z=f(u,v)$ where $u=\frac{\sin x}{y^2}$ and $v=\frac{1}{y}$. Finding the first derivative with respec to $x$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\frac{\cos x}{y^2}$$
So far I'm pretty sure I'm correct. Now for finding second derivative.
$$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\frac{\cos x}{y^2}\right)=\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial u}\frac{\cos x}{y^2}-\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\frac{\sin x}{y^2}$$
Now I'm really not sure about this. The second term seems okay to me. It's the first one $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial u}$ that I'm not sure about and one that my teacher seemed to have a problem with, but he didn't explain what the problem was. Can anyone point out where's my mistake?

Comment: You can calcuate $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial u}$ in same way as in first step.

Comment: If I understand correctly it's like this $\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x \partial u}=\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial u^2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial u^2}\frac{\cos x}{y^2}$. Do I got that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial u}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u^2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$

Let me also use some other notation
$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = f'_1u'_1$

$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial f'_1}{\partial x}u'_1+ f'_1 \frac{\partial  u'_1}{\partial x}=f''_{11}(u'_1)^2 + f'_1 u''_{11}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
Writing:
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
$$
is a shorthand notation for:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (z(u(x,y), v(x,y)))
=\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial a}\right)(u(x,y), v(x,y))\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)
+\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial b}\right)(u(x,y), v(x,y))\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,y)
$$
if $z=z(a,b)$.